# Error "could not be changed because the data didn't validate"

Tags: django, django-views

I can't update extended user profile

In views.py:

## views.py

```
def profile(request, user_id):
user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
user_info = get_object_or_404(UserInfor, user_id=user.id)
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=user_info)
    user = user_form.save(commit=True)
    user_info = profile_form.save(commit=True)
    user.save()
    user_info.save()
    return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', {'user': user_form, 'user_info': profile_form, 'user_id': user_id})
else:
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=user_info)
    return render(request, 'pages/profile.html', {'user': user_form, 'user_info': profile_form, 'user_id': user_id})
```

How can I fix error?

Comment: You should call **`Form.is_valid()`** method

Comment: but informaton can't updated

Comment: use `commit=False` when returning model object from form data